# How to combine all rows in array as one input, with foreach()?

Tags: php

I am trying to combine all the rows in an array into one row for a product-order summary. So what i have right now

`$cartitem = $item['name'] ."  qty  ". $item['quantity'] ."  IDR ". $item['price']. "  IDR " . $item_price;`

`foreach($cartitem as $rows)`

`{ echo $rows;}`

Output (as of now) = Product Name qty 2 IDR 15000 IDR 30000

This is the output i am aiming for, but i need to display all rows. The output above only returns the last row. Is this possible with `foreach()`, then to `implode` all rows to insert into a single column in database?

*UPDATE:
So this is the source of the input arrays(cart system)
*skip a few lines*

```
$item_array = array($productByCode["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode["name"], 'code'=>$productByCode["code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode["price"], 'image'=>$productByCode["image"]));

            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])){
                if(in_array($productByCode["name"], array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))){
                foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v){
                    if($productByCode["code"] == $k){
                        if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])){
                        $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = 0;
                        }
                        $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];
                        }
                    }
                }  else { 
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$item_array);
                }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $item_array;
// Above is the cart add-product action
```

Here is the cart ouput session

```
foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
    $item_price = $item["quantity"]*$item["price"];
?>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $item['image'];?>" class="cart-item-image"><?php echo $item["name"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $item['quantity']; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo "IDR ".$item['price']; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo "IDR ". number_format($item_price,2); ?></td>
    <td style="text-align-center;"><a href="cart2.php?action=remove&code=<?php echo $item['code'];?>" class="btn-remove">Hapus</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    $total_quantity += $item["quantity"];
    $total_price += ($item_price);
    // Count rows input
    echo count($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
}
?>
// Cart Output Session
```

I have tried to check the rows by `print_r($_SESSION["cart_item"])`, and it shows in formation as in `$item_array`. I need a neater output to store into one column in database.

Comment: $result = implode(' ',$item);

Comment: tell me what have you tried so far,post your php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain the pseudo logic.

Take a variable `$allProducts`

Loop over products.

Append the `implode()` ded string to it.

Now, every time, the latest result will be appended to `$allProducts` string.

Lastly echo the string.

Like...

```
foreach ($cartitem as $rows) {
 $allProducts .= implode(',', $rows);
}
echo $allProducts;
```

***EDIT from Bernardy Gosal** 
So i have tried using this method, which seems to me to make a new array, and i made it like this.

```
$allProducts= [];
foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $key => $value){
    $allProducts[$value['name']]= $value['quantity']."*".$value['price']."  =Rp".$value["quantity"]*$value["price"]."<br>"; 

}
print_r($allProducts);
$imp_pro .= implode('  ', $allProducts);
print_r($imp_pro);
```

It results in neat output

```
Array ( [Central Deluxe 120x200] => 1*1400000 =Rp1400000 <br>
[Central Deluxe 180x200] => 1*1850000 =Rp1850000 <br>
[Central Deluxe 200x200 Pillow Top] => 3*2300000 =Rp6900000
)<br>
But when i try to implode this it seems to lose the $key <br>
1*1400000 =Rp1400000 <br>
1*1850000 =Rp1850000 <br>
3*2300000 =Rp6900000
```